# Response never ends with PageAsyncTask?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, asynchronous, pageasynctask

*I have to support an old project which uses `PageAsyncTask` with webforms vs2010 fw4.*

However this simple code  does compile + execute( no errors in debug mode / trace mode) but the response never ends.

*Looking in debug mode + breakpoints - it reaches all stages of code.*

```
public partial class _Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 IAsyncResult BeginGetData(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=... Asynchronous Processing=True;");
        var sql = @"   SELECT   [NAME] FROM [WebERP].[dbo].[t]";
        {
            SqlCommand _cmd = null;
            try
            {
                _cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                _cmd.CommandTimeout = 100000;
                con.Open();
                return _cmd.BeginExecuteReader(EndGetData, _cmd);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (_cmd != null) _cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    void EndGetData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        (ar.AsyncState as SqlCommand).EndExecuteReader(ar);
        Response.Write(1111); // HttpContext.Current.Response also doesnt help
    }

    void TimeoutData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Response.Write("Could not retrieve data!");
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PageAsyncTask task = new PageAsyncTask(BeginGetData, EndGetData, TimeoutData, null, true);
        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(task);
        Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();    
    }
}
```

**Question**

The response never ends. All I see is :

[image]

What am I missing ?

(nb `Async="true"` is on the page directive , also  - code was simplified just to describe the case )

Comment: I don't think you should pass the same `EndGetData` to both `BeginExecuteReader` and `PageAsyncTask`.

Comment: @Noseratio ouch.... thank you. probably missed that. the correct line should be `return _cmd.BeginExecuteReader(callback(!!!!), state);` where callback declared at `IAsyncResult BeginGetData(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback callback, object state)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you pass the same `BeginGetData` and `EndGetData` callbacks to both `BeginExecuteReader` and `new PageAsyncTask()`. They should be different: what you pass to `PageAsyncTask` is "outer" to what you pass to `BeginExecuteReader`.

You'd call `BeginExecuteReader` from the begin callback you'd pass to `PageAsyncTask`, and you'd be actually required to call the `AsyncCallback callback` provided to you there by ASP.NET (you'd call it when the async operation would have finished, i.e., from your `EndGetData`).

It would be so much easier if you could use the `PageAsyncTask(Func<Task>)` override, but I don't think you can target .NET 4.5 with VS2010.